# Turning off ADB over WiFi through ADB shell?

Tags: android, shell, adb, android-developer-api

I would like to turn off enabled ADB over WiFi from inside ADB shell after executing a shell script before it. The main reason is that I simply want to start some script, and get rid of overhead caused by ADB over WiFi connection. I do need a WiFi connection itself, so `adb shell "svc wifi disable"` will not work.

Is there a way to control this development option remotely somehow without touching the screen?

Or possibly there is a `am start` command that could do this? Something like `am start -n com.android...` or `am start -a android.intent.action...`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40680864/1778421

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`adbd` is the adb daemon that runs on your devices, awaiting connection.

issuing `stop adbd` should kill it - you may have to run this as root, should stop adb on the device, and disconnect your active shell.

*edit*

just tried this and it worked for me, running cyanogenmod. using `adb connect <ip>`, and entering an adb shell, `su` for super user privileges, and then issue `stop adbd`. your shell should terminate, and you will not be able to reconnect until you restart it from your device. (shell or settings menu)

Comment: Because it turns off both USB ADB and ADB over WiFi probably. Thanks. I will give it a try.