# How to Turn on/off debug mode using adb command in android

Tags: android, adb, debug-mode

I don't know it is possible or not to turn ON/OFF android debug mode using adb command.

Is there really any adb command exist to turn ON/OFF android debug mode. Please if any suggest or any kinds of way around will be highly appreciated.

Comment: ok what is adb? literally?

Comment: @Selvin So, if debug mode is ON then how can I disable that using adb command.

Comment: prolly on rooted device you can stop adb deamon on device ... also you may play with setprop

Comment: @Selvin Alex answer give me the solution.

Answer (score 15):

You can turn off *USB Debugging* with `settings put global adb_enabled 0` command.

Comment: you need to run `adb shell` and then in shell paste `settings put global adb_enabled 0`.